# Performance problem selecting large log table with one join

Tags: query-performance, mariadb

I've a Log-Tabelle with approximately 13 million rows. The table structure is (truncated) as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE `dmsserver_status_log` (
      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `timestamp` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
      `level` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `logger_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `message` text NOT NULL,
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

- *id* is the PK and AUTO_INCREMENT
- *customer_id* and timestamp have a KEY each
- *customer_id* has a FOREIGN KEY to the 'customer' table

The customer table structure is (truncated) as follows and have approximately 1700 rows:

```
    CREATE TABLE `customer` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      [...]
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

- *id* is the PK and AUTO_INCREMENT
- *number* is UNIQUE KEY

There a many more columns and some more keys on these columns but I can't imagine that this is related to my performance problem (?)

If I query my log table (without a join) I receive the result in a short time:

```
    SELECT
        `timestamp`,
        `level`,
        logger_name,
        message
    FROM dmsserver_status_log as log
    WHERE
        `timestamp` > '2020-03-01 00:00:00'
        AND message LIKE '%fehlgeschlagen%'
    ORDER BY
        `timestamp` ASC;
```

In this example I get 57 hits in about a second. This is okay for me. 
If I expand my select with a JOIN on the customer table the same select needs round about 30 seconds or more to complete:

```
    SELECT
        `timestamp`,
        `level`,
        logger_name,
        message,
        customer.`number`
    FROM dmsserver_status_log as log
        JOIN customer ON customer.id = log.customer_id
    WHERE
        `timestamp` > '2020-03-01 00:00:00'
        AND message LIKE '%fehlgeschlagen%'
    ORDER BY
        `timestamp` ASC;
```

Depending on my query and the range of the timestamp this query could take several or dozen of minutes..
I just dont understand why this select take so much time to complete.

Here is the 'EXPLAIN EXTENDED' output of obove select with join:

```
    id  select_type   `table`    `type`    possible_keys            `key`          key_len    `ref`         `rows`  filtered     Extra
    1   SIMPLE        customer   index     PRIMARY                  number         32                        1749   100          Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
    1   SIMPLE        log        ref       customer_id,timestamp    customer_id    4          customer.id     515   100          Using where
```

Could someone explain to me why it takes so much more time to join the second table?

**Edit**:

As requested here are the Results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE dmsserver_status_log`

```
    CREATE TABLE `dmsserver_status_log` (
      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `timestamp` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
      `thread_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `level` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `logger_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `source_host` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `message` text NOT NULL,
      `stacktrace` text,
      `mdc` text,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
      KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
      CONSTRAINT `dmsserver_status_log_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17996215 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and here are the Results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE customer`

```
    CREATE TABLE `customer` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `headquarter_customer_number` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Angabe des Hauptbetriebs wenn dies eine Filiale ist',
      `it_location_customer_number` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Angabe des EDV-Standorts wenn dieser Kunde keine eigene EDV hat',
      `customer_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `address_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `characteristic_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `iban` varchar(34) DEFAULT NULL,
      `bic` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `bank` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `newsletter` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `newsletter_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `invoice_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email-Adresse für den Empfang von Rechnungen als PDF',
      `api_password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Zugangspasswort für den Zugriff auf unsere API',
      `comments` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      `valid_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
      `create_time` datetime NOT NULL,
      `create_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `change_time` datetime NOT NULL,
      `change_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `number` (`number`),
      KEY `change_by` (`change_by`),
      KEY `characteristic_id` (`characteristic_id`),
      KEY `customer_type_id` (`customer_type_id`),
      KEY `address_id` (`address_id`),
      KEY `valid_id` (`valid_id`),
      KEY `create_by` (`create_by`),
      KEY `headquarter_customer_number` (`headquarter_customer_number`),
      KEY `it_location_customer_number` (`it_location_customer_number`),
      CONSTRAINT `customer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_type_id`) REFERENCES `customer_type` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `customer_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `customer_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`characteristic_id`) REFERENCES `customer_characteristic` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `customer_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`create_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `customer_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`change_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `customer_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`headquarter_customer_number`) REFERENCES `customer` (`number`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `customer_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`it_location_customer_number`) REFERENCES `customer` (`number`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2540 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: How many rows does customer table have? Also, have you executed analyze on both tables?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE dmsserver_status_log; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE customer;  for analysis.

Comment: I've just added requested outputs to my original message. The customer table have approx. 1700 rows

Comment: Thank you for the Show Create Tables.

Answer (score 2):

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each variant.

What version of MariaDB?  (Optimizations have changed in this area.)

Also try these variations

This one isolates the filtering into a derived table, thereby minimizing the need for reaching into the other table.

```
SELECT  log.`timestamp`, log.`level`, log.logger_name, log.message,
        c.`number`
    FROM (
        SELECT  log1.customer_id, log1.`timestamp`,
                log1.`level`, log1.logger_name,
                log1.message
            FROM  dmsserver_status_log AS log1 
            WHERE  `timestamp` > '2020-03-01 00:00:00'
              AND  message LIKE '%fehlgeschlagen%'
         ) AS log
    JOIN  customer AS c  ON c.id = log.customer_id
    ORDER BY  log.`timestamp` ASC;
```

This one defers looking at the second table in a different way.

```
SELECT   `timestamp`, `level`, logger_name, message,
         ( SELECT `number` FROM customer
                     WHERE customer.id = log.customer_id ) AS "number"
    FROM  dmsserver_status_log as log
    JOIN  customer  ON customer.id = log.customer_id
    WHERE  `timestamp` > '2020-03-01 00:00:00'
      AND  message LIKE '%fehlgeschlagen%'
    ORDER BY  `timestamp` ASC;
```

Depending on the version of MySQL/MariaDB, the three variations may be optimized differently.

If you are searching for a "word", consider using `FULLTEXT(message)` and `MATCH(message) AGAINST ('+fehlgeschlagen' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.  It should run a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

You have individual indices (a.k.a. keys) on `customer_id` and `timestamp` in the `dmsserver_status_log` table. MariaDB can usually only use one index for any given query. So when you change the query to include a join, then MariaDB has to choose one of the indices to use.

What you need instead is a suitable *compound* index on your `dmsserver_status_log` table that can support relevant conditions in your `WHERE` clause, the `JOIN` and `ORDER BY` columns at the same time.

So the index you need would probably be `CREATE INDEX dmsserver_status_log_idx1 ON (customer_id, timestamp)`. Note that the order of the columns is important. (If the `EXPLAIN` shows that the optimizer will not use this index, then you can try to re-create it with the columns in the reverse order. Query optimisation can be difficult ...)

Note that the `message` column which also appears in your `WHERE` clause will not benefit from being in the compound index with the particular query as it stands because you have a wildcard before the search string.

You may want to consider removing the existing individual indices on `customer_id` and `timestamp` if you only care about good performance on the particular JOIN query. Maintaining a lot of indexes in a table means slower `INSERT`s and they also take up some memory.

For reference, here's an article about building indices for MariaDB/MySQL:
[Building the best INDEX for a given SELECT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)

Answer (score -1):

Martin, 
The EXPLAIN indicates customer was the first table used, you likely know that you want the LOG to be selected first to get only rows > 2020-03-01.  You should be able to make that happen with SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ......
and change

```
 JOIN customer ON customer.id = log.customer_id
```

to

```
 JOIN customer ON log.customer_id = customer.id
```

Please post new time required with this STRAIGHT_JOIN version.

Comment: I doubt seriously whether x=y is optimized any differently than y=x.

Comment: The major problem with `STRAIGHT_JOIN` is that if later a `level` is added to the `customer`, that's all of a sudden a join criteria. It should never be used except in the very extreme cases like identical tables.

Comment: @martin-fernau, Please post your current query and EXPLAIN EXTENDED test results so we can see what the optimizer did with your query. Thanks